# Mongoose aggregate using $addFields and $match by added field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to run the aggregate query in Mongo using $addFields and $match

```
.aggregate([
        {
            $addFields: {
                level: { $sum: '$members.level' },
            },
        },
        {
            $match: {
                level: { $gte: level }
            },
        },
        {
            $project: {
                _id: 0,
                logo: 1,
                name: 1,
                level: 1,
                id: '$_id',
                joinType: 1,
                countryId: 1,
                minimumJoinLevel: 1,
                membersCount: { $size: '$members' },
            },
        },
    ])
```

The issue is that level is not an indexed field and has been calculated in the query

My question is: how I can run this query efficiently, avoid "COLLSCAN" and make it "IXSCAN" execution

Comment: I think you will need to maintain the `level` field through application code/db trigger to have an index on it.

Comment: You can replace the first `$addFields` stage with the last `$project` stage (and include the `level` field calculation in the $project). The aggregation can do with 2 stages.

Comment: @prasad_ Can you show an example, please?

Comment: @ray I am trying to avoid, but it is a solution

Comment: Any assumptions we can make on the "members.level" value?